# Netbeans/maven sync issue with generated code

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

When we use Netbeans with a project that generates code, it seems that Netbeans has a hard time keeping in sync with the generated code, often displaying errors that are phantoms, or requiring me to "reload POM" to see the generated code in the project tree.  This can get quite frustrating, because it is hard to see what is a real error and what is a phantom.  The code-generation integration into the maven project is controlled by a maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-source</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-source</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/</source>
          <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/resources/</source>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and the generated code itself is created by a custom tool execution step:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>ipc-generator</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
      ... run the code generator ...
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there a recommended way to keep NetBeans in sync with generated code?  I don't normally run the full code-generating build from within Netbeans, because it insists on running all of the tests, which I don't usually want.  So I run the build from the command-line instead, and Netbeans unsuccessfully tries to sync up.  It is sometimes better if I close NetBeans, run the build, and re-open NetBeans.